# counting values, consecutive and not on a grouped table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an SQL Table  named samples, defined like this:

```
sampledate (datetime, 24 records per day per parameter)
parameterID (int)
value (decimal)
valid (bit, 1=valid data, 0=invalid data)
```

the couple sampledate and parameterid are unique.

each sampledate is in the format 02/02/2011 12:00, so there are 24 rows per parameterid per day or less (a probe can fail or be in maintenance, for example, and it will output less than 24 samples).

I have to calculate the average daily values per parameter.  The average is valid for a given day only if

1. at least 18 valid values are present
2. no more than 5 invalid **consecutive** values are present

Condition 1) is pretty simple to achieve, for a given @parameter:

```
  SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, FLOOR(CONVERT(FLOAT, sampledate))) as avgdate,
         AVG(value) as avg, parameterID, 
         isValid = CASE  
           WHEN COUNT(value) > 17 THEN 1
           ELSE 0
         END 
    FROM samples
   WHERE parameterId=@parameter
GROUP BY parameterId, CONVERT(DATETIME, FLOOR(CONVERT(FLOAT, sampledate))), valid
  HAVING valid = 1  
ORDER BY sampledate
```

How can I add condition 2, which boils down to counting consecutive 0s in a 24hrs span, possibly with the best performances?

we have millions of samples, and cursors are slow.

Comment: So it takes 5 *consecutive* invalid values to make the day as a whole invalid?

Comment: I presume that "sampledate" is actually a full date-time value, including the time component, and that no two records have the same parameterID and sampledate?  (these two fields could be used to form a unique constraint or primary key?)

Comment: exactely.Dems. I apologize for not having stated it clearly. sample datetimes are like 2/2/2011 12:00, one each hour (or less, some hours can be skipped if a probe fails or is in maintenance, for example). The couple date and parameter id is unique.
I'm editing the question.

Comment: 18 valid values at least, but no 5 consecutive invalid values. That gives a total of 23. So, suppose there was exactly one fail and it happened in-between those 5 invalid values. Should we apply the rule #2?

Comment: that's an intereeeeeesting question, I'm talking about it right now with the physics...

Comment: Revised the Recursive-CTE part of my answer to not use a LEFT JOIN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And here goes my recursive CTE solution, and it is parameterisable:

```
WITH
seq_samples AS (
  SELECT
    sampledate, parameterID, value, valid,
    avgdate = CAST(FLOOR(CAST(sampledate AS float)) AS datetime),
    rownum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY parameterID, CAST(FLOOR(CAST(sampledate AS float)) AS datetime)
      ORDER BY sampledate)
  FROM samples
),
rec_samples AS (
  SELECT
    sampledate, parameterID, value, valid, avgdate, rownum,
    inv_seq_num = 1 - valid
  FROM seq_samples
  WHERE rownum = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    ss.sampledate, ss.parameterID, ss.value, ss.valid, ss.avgdate, ss.rownum,
    inv_seq_num = CASE ss.valid WHEN 1 THEN 0 ELSE rs.inv_seq_num + 1 END
  FROM seq_samples ss
    INNER JOIN rec_samples rs ON ss.avgdate = rs.avgdate
      AND ss.parameterID = rs.parameterID AND ss.rownum = rs.rownum + 1
)
SELECT
  avgdate,
  parameterID,
  avgvalue = AVG(value)
FROM rec_samples
GROUP BY avgdate, parameterID
HAVING SUM(CAST(valid AS int)) >= @minimal_valid_count
   AND MAX(inv_seq_num)        <= @critical_invalid_count
```

Your idea basically is implemented here. Additional numbering is used, which is only applied to invalid rows and is only broken by date transitions and valid values' occurrences. In the end `MAX` is applied to the numbering column to find out if the max number has not exceeded `@critical_invalid_count`. And for the other parameter it is obviously enough to check the sum of `valid` attributes.

So, there you are.

---

**EDIT** for the `seq_samples` CTE (to be applied to your adapted version of the original query).

```
seq_samples AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    rownum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY parameterID, avgdate
      ORDER BY sampledate)
  FROM (
    SELECT
      sampledate, parameterID, value, valid,
      avgdate = CAST(FLOOR(CAST(sampledate AS float)) AS datetime)
    FROM samples
  ) s
),
```

SSMS showed me significant, practically unbelievable difference in performance between my original query and the modified one. (This is only based on the figures from the estimated execution plan.) I don't know what adaptations you had to make to my original solution, but I hope the improvement I've witnessed will not be completely lost because of them.

Comment: hey, this is brilliant. I've just adapted to the real db, and it works.
BUT, it's slow. I've compared this solution to the cursor based one,  over a small dataset. The results were: 2 mins for the cursor solution and 7 for the recursive cte one. 
I'm keeping the question open for a couple of days, just to see if someone comes up with a faster solution. If not, I'll accept this.
thanks

Comment: @pomarc: Wow, 7 mins versus 2... quite a gap. I'm inclined to blame it on `seq_samples` for the most part. Possibly it's double conversion, repeated too, and the partitioned `ROW_NUMBER()`. I'm going to try to change this CTE and I think it will be more convenient to post it separately from the complete query rather than change it in-place.

Comment: @pomarc: Do you have an index covering parameterID and avgdate?

Comment: @Dems: You probably meant `sampledate`, not `avgdate`.

Comment: Yes, there is an index on date and parameterid (to be true, the real table is a little more complex, we also have two more fields which individuate the monitoring station, but we can ignore here). 
I'm @ my client today, and will try your new solutions, comparing them against the cursor one, and let you know.
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A couple of thoughts and comments...

There are many ways of making a date-time into a date only value.  I use DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, ), 0).  But for the following code I suggest we just pretend there is a justDate field, to make things shorter :)

Sequence is important, and the table doesn't have a "sequence id".  ROW_NUMBER() can give this to you...

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY parameter_id, justDate ORDER BY sampledate) AS "sequence_id"
```

There seem to be a couple of ways of doing this.

For each sample, join on to the next sample, five times.  I don't like it, but it's probably the simplest option...

```
WITH
  sequenced_samples
AS
(
  SELECT
    parameterID AS "parameter_id",
    sampledate AS "sample_date_time",
    DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, sampledate), 0) AS "sample_date",
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY parameter_id, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, sampledate), 0) ORDER BY sampledate) AS "sequence_id",
    CASE WHEN valid = 1 THEN value ELSE NULL END as "value",
    -(valid - 1) AS "invalid" -- turns 1 to 0, and 0 to 1
  FROM
    samples
)

SELECT
  "sample_1".parameter_id,
  "sample_1".sample_date,
  AVG(value) AS average_value
FROM
  samples                "sample_1"
LEFT JOIN
  samples                "sample_2"
    ON  "sample_2".parameter_id = "sample_1".parameter_id
    AND "sample_2".sample_date  = "sample_1".sample_date
    AND "sample_2".sequence_id  = "sample_1".sequence_id + 1
LEFT JOIN
  samples                "sample_3"
    ON  "sample_3".parameter_id = "sample_1".parameter_id
    AND "sample_3".sample_date  = "sample_1".sample_date
    AND "sample_3".sequence_id  = "sample_1".sequence_id + 2
LEFT JOIN
  samples                "sample_4"
    ON  "sample_4".parameter_id = "sample_1".parameter_id
    AND "sample_4".sample_date  = "sample_1".sample_date
    AND "sample_4".sequence_id  = "sample_1".sequence_id + 3
LEFT JOIN
  samples                "sample_5"
    ON  "sample_5".parameter_id = "sample_1".parameter_id
    AND "sample_5".sample_date  = "sample_1".sample_date
    AND "sample_5".sequence_id  = "sample_1".sequence_id + 4
GROUP BY
  "sample_1".parameter_id,
  "sample_1".sample_date
HAVING
  5 > MAX("sample_1".invalid + "sample_2".invalid + "sample_3".invalid + "sample_4".invalid + "sample_5".invalid)
  AND 17 < (COUNT(*) - SUM("sample_1".invalid))
```

The next is slightly more intelegent (but only slightly) but I'm not sat anywhere with access to MS SQL Server, so I can't tell if it's any more performant.

Instead of 4 joins, join just once, but matching 5 sequential samples.  The doing two levels of grouping.

```
WITH
  sequenced_samples
AS
(
  SELECT
    parameterID AS "parameter_id",
    sampledate AS "sample_date_time",
    DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, sampledate), 0) AS "sample_date",
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY parameter_id, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, sampledate), 0) ORDER BY sampledate) AS "sequence_id",
    CASE WHEN valid = 1 THEN value ELSE NULL END AS "value",
    -(valid - 1) AS "invalid"  -- Turns 0 to 1, and 1 to 0
  FROM
    samples
)
,
  checked_samples
AS
(
SELECT
  "sample".parameter_id,
  "sample".sample_date,
  "sample".value,
  "sample".invalid,
  SUM("next_5_samples".invalid) AS "sequence_invalidity"
FROM
  samples                "sample"
INNER JOIN
  samples                "next_5_samples"
    ON  "next_5_samples".parameter_id  = "sample".parameter_id
    AND "next_5_samples".sample_date   = "sample".sample_date
    AND "next_5_samples".sequence_id  >= "sample".sequence_id + 1
    AND "next_5_samples".sequence_id  <= "sample".sequence_id + 4
GROUP BY
  "sample".parameter_id,
  "sample".sample_date,
  "sample".valid,
  "sample".value
)
SELECT
  parameter_id,
  sample_date,
  AVG(value)
FROM
  checked_samples
GROUP BY
  parameter_id,
  sample_date
HAVING
  5 > MAX(sequence_invalidity)
  AND 17 < (COUNT(*) - SUM(invalid))
```

The final option is to use recursive Common Table Expressions to loop through the records one by one.  This is more complicated to code that a Cursor, but is (in my experience) much faster.

**EDIT:** *The following query had a left join in the recursive-CTE, and now it doesn't.*

```
WITH
  sequenced_samples
AS
(
  SELECT
    parameterID AS "parameter_id",
    sampledate AS "sample_date_time",
    DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, sampledate), 0) AS "sample_date",
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY parameter_id, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, sampledate), 0) ORDER BY sampledate) AS "sequence_id",
    value,
    valid
  FROM
    samples
)
,
  recursed_totals
AS
(
SELECT
  parameter_id,
  sample_date,
  sequence_id - 1                           AS "next_sequence_id",
  CASE WHEN valid = 1 THEN value ELSE 0 END AS "cumulative_value",
  valid                                     AS "cumulative_count",
  CASE WHEN valid = 1 THEN 0     ELSE 1 END AS "cumulative_invalid",
  CASE WHEN valid = 1 THEN 0     ELSE 1 END AS "max_cumulative_invalid"
FROM
  sequenced_samples
WHERE
  sequence_id = (
                 SELECT
                   COUNT(*)
                 FROM
                   sequenced_samples "look_up"
                 WHERE
                       "look_up".parameter_id = sequenced_samples.parameter_id
                   AND "look_up".sample_date  = sequenced_samples.sample_date
                )

UNION ALL

SELECT
  "cumulative_samples".parameter_id,
  "cumulative_samples".sample_date,
  "next_sample".sequence_id - 1,
  "cumulative_samples".cumuatlive_value + CASE WHEN "next_sample".valid = 1 THEN "next_sample".value ELSE 0 END,
  "cumulative_samples".valid + ISNULL("next_sample".valid, 0),
  CASE
    WHEN "next_sample".valid = 0 THEN "cumulative_samples".cumulative_invalid + 1
    WHEN "cumulative_samples".cumulative_invalid = 5 THEN 5
    ELSE 0
  END,
  CASE
    WHEN "next_sample".valid = 1 THEN "cumulative_samples".max_cumulative_invalid
    WHEN "cumulative_samples".cumulative_invalid = "cumulative_samples".max_cumulative_invalid THEN "cumulative_samples".max_cumulative_invalid + 1
    ELSE "cumulative_samples".max_cumulative_invalid
  END
FROM
  recursed_totals   AS "cumulative_samples"
INNER JOIN
  sequenced_samples AS "next_sample"
    ON  "next_sample".parameter_id = "cumulative_samples".parameter_id
    AND "next_sample".sample_date  = "cumulative_samples".sample_date
    AND "next_sample".sequence_id  = "cumulative_samples".next_sequence_id
)
SELECT
  parameter_id,
  sample_date,
  CAST(cumulative_value AS FLOAT) / CAST(cumulative_count AS FLOAT) AS "average",
  cumulative_count AS "valid_samples",
  max_cumulative_invalid AS "max_consecutive_invalid_samples"
FROM
  recursed_totals
WHERE
  parameter_id = @parameter_id
```

Comment: I don't have SQL anywhere near me, so I had to make a few edits, and I'm sure there are still errors in it.  But hpoefully it will give you a few ideas.  The recursive CTE version is possibly the fastest, but is also the most complex to understand (and debug my typos)

Comment: Just read at MSDN: `The following items are not allowed in the CTE_query_definition of a recursive member:  [...]  > LEFT, RIGHT, OUTER JOIN (INNER JOIN is allowed)  [...]` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)

Comment: @Andriy: Good point, recoded to count down from the max so that the recursion always terminates at a "next_sequnce_id" of 0.

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution that uses basically the same approach as the one used by Dems. I think the logic in my solution is a bit different. (Or maybe it is just differently structured...)

```
WITH sortedsamples AS (
  SELECT
    sampledate,
    parameterID,
    value,
    valid,
    avgdate = CAST(FLOOR(CAST(sampledate AS float)) AS datetime),
    rownum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY parameterID, CAST(FLOOR(CAST(sampledate AS float)) AS datetime)
      ORDER BY sampledate
    )
  FROM samples
)
SELECT
  ss1.parameterID,
  ss1.avgdate,
  avg = AVG(value),
  isValid = CAST(CASE
    WHEN SUM(CAST(ss1.valid AS int)) < 18 THEN 0
    ELSE MIN(CAST(ss1.valid | ISNULL(ss2.valid, 1) | ISNULL(ss3.valid, 1)
                            | ISNULL(ss4.valid, 1) | ISNULL(ss5.valid, 1) AS int))
  END AS bit)
FROM sortedsamples ss1
  LEFT JOIN sortedsamples ss2 ON ss1.avgdate = ss2.avgdate
    AND ss1.parameterID = ss2.parameterID AND ss1.rownum = ss2.rownum + 1
  LEFT JOIN sortedsamples ss3 ON ss1.avgdate = ss3.avgdate
    AND ss1.parameterID = ss3.parameterID AND ss1.rownum = ss3.rownum + 2
  LEFT JOIN sortedsamples ss4 ON ss1.avgdate = ss4.avgdate
    AND ss1.parameterID = ss4.parameterID AND ss1.rownum = ss4.rownum + 3
  LEFT JOIN sortedsamples ss5 ON ss1.avgdate = ss5.avgdate
    AND ss1.parameterID = ss5.parameterID AND ss1.rownum = ss5.rownum + 4
GROUP BY ss1.parameterID, ss1.avgdate
```

Comment: The MIN of ORs is basically just an algebraic manipulation and shoudl perform identically.

Comment: oh, and you've including values in the average, even when valid = 0.  I'm not sure if that's correct or not, I assumed they would need excluding, but it is just an assumption.

Comment: @Dems: 1. No argue about that. I only meant to say that my solution is similar to yours basically, but it just happened to be so and I didn't base it on your solution, which, as I hoped, should partly be seen from the differing calculation logic. 2. Again, I'm ready to agree with you. I was just following the OP's example query where it seemed as if the invalid averages were to be included as well.

Answer (score 0):

Out of your millions of samples, what percent have less than 5 invalid values per day?  If it's a high enough percentage, you're ok, because you can easily exclude them from cursor processing.

If the number of samples with 5 or more invalid values per day is still in the millions, you may be in for a long wait.

Answer (score 0):

your solutions are quite interesting (and I've learnt a lot from them) but I wonder if they can be improved.

For instance, all the solutions (maybe except the one using the recursive cte) are not parametric in the number  (N) of invalid consecutive samples. 
I can imagine that I could have in the future different N for different years or parameters.

I was wondering if a solution could be devised starting from the rownum() solutions: If I could find a way to reset the count ate each break on the valid column, I could simply invalidate a day where I find a row having rownum>N and valid=0, that would be super simple, fast and versatile.

I try to explain this idea better:

let's say I could use rownum or a similar function to obtain this:

```
date                       par    value        valid     rownum

2010-01-26 00:00:00.000 25  14.0000000000       1      1
2010-01-26 01:00:00.000 25  15.3000001907       1      2
2010-01-26 02:00:00.000 25  16.8999996185       1      3
2010-01-26 03:00:00.000 25  13.6000003815       1      4
2010-01-26 04:00:00.000 25  16.2000007629       1      5
2010-01-26 05:00:00.000 25  12.1999998093      -1      1
2010-01-26 06:00:00.000 25  17.2000007629      -1      2
2010-01-26 07:00:00.000 25  16.2999992371       1      1
2010-01-26 08:00:00.000 25  18.2999992371       1      2
2010-01-26 09:00:00.000 25  15.0000000000       1      3
2010-01-26 10:00:00.000 25  17.7000007629       1      4
2010-01-26 11:00:00.000 25  16.5000000000       1      5
2010-01-26 12:00:00.000 25  17.3999996185       1      6
2010-01-26 13:00:00.000 25  17.7000007629       1      7
2010-01-26 14:00:00.000 25  18.2999992371       1      8
2010-01-26 15:00:00.000 25  15.1000003815      -1      1
2010-01-26 16:00:00.000 25  16.5000000000      -1      2
2010-01-26 17:00:00.000 25  10.3999996185      -1      3
2010-01-26 18:00:00.000 25  10.8999996185      -1      4
2010-01-26 19:00:00.000 25  10.1000003815      -1      5  <-----!!!!  
2010-01-26 20:00:00.000 25  13.6999998093       1      1
2010-01-26 21:00:00.000 25  12.6999998093       1      2
2010-01-26 22:00:00.000 25  15.3999996185      -1      1
2010-01-26 23:00:00.000 25  8.6000003815       -1      2
```

if N=5,   the existence of the row

```
2010-01-26 19:00:00.000 25  10.1000003815      -1      5
```

would indicate that the whole day is not valid (let alone the total number of invalid data)

What do you think about this idea?

(I don't know if this should have been an edit or a distinct answer)

Comment: If you've learned a lot from the answers shouldn't you upvote them? It looks like some of them probably took quite a long time.

Comment: Thanks for the upvoting. Your idea sounds quite nice, yet I can hardly see it implemented using a pure set-based approach, even though my understanding of recursive CTEs is quite poor presently, to be frank. The particular idea of checking for the existence of a row with rownum=N(critical) and using that fact to dismiss a whole bunch of rows... Well, I'm going to try to find my own recursive CTE solution anyway (keeping your idea in mind too), even if only to get to know the concept better, and if so, why not using as an exercise such an interesting problem as yours?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another answer using CROSS APPLY and avoiding using ROW_NUMBER().

If, however, more than 5 samples happen at exactly the same time, for the same parameterID, this won't work correctly.  If that's the case, you need ROW_NUMBER() again.

```
SELECT
  parameterID                                              AS "parameter_id",
  DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, sampledate), 0)            AS "sample_date",
  SUM(value)                                               AS "total",
  SUM(CASE WHEN valid = 1 THEN value ELSE 0 END)           AS "total_valid",
  COUNT(*)                                                 AS "count",
  SUM(valid)                                               AS "count_valid",
  MAX(invalid)                                             AS "date_invalidated"
FROM
  samples
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT
    CASE WHEN SUM(valid) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS "invalid"
  FROM
  (
    SELECT TOP 5
      valid
    FROM
      samples AS "5_samples"
    WHERE
          "5_samples".parameterID  = "samples".parameterID
      AND "5_samples".sampledate  >= "samples".sampledate
      AND "5_samples".sampledate  <  DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, "samples".sampledate), 1)
    ORDER BY
      sampledate
  )
    AS "data"
)
  AS "check"
WHERE
  parameterID = @parameterID
GROUP BY
  parameter_id,
  DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, sampledate), 0)
```